# Spanning set for a free Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

Given a free Lie algebra $L$ over a field $K$ with $k$ generators $x_1,\ldots, x_k$, is it true that the $K$-span of the set

$$\{[x_i, v] : 1\leq i \leq k, v\in L\}$$

is the entire Lie algebra $L$? If so, how could one prove this? If not, can we obtain something similar, e.g., if we assign weight one to every generator, it is true for odd weight elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y = \{[x_i,v] | v \in L, 1 \leq i \leq k \}$.  Since $L$ is free, $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are not in $Y$, so the answer is negative.

On the other hand, as a vector space $L = X \oplus Y$ where $X$ is the $K$-span of the generators. So $Y$ generates "almost everything".